# Convert List Variable to string

Tags: r, string, list, variables

I have the following code:

```
     #subsets of different criteria

     IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition = subset(SelectedRNumberOnlyOutlierRejectionOrdered, 
                                     Job..R == "14047/2"
                                     & Weight_Initial > weight
                                     )

      IAEA_C2_EAstd = subset(SelectedRNumberOnlyOutlierRejectionOrdered, 
                             Job..R == "14047/2"
                             & Weight_Initial > weight
                             & AMS_Timetable_From_Results..Standard_Prep_Type == "EA"
                             )

      IAEA_C2_STstd = subset(SelectedRNumberOnlyOutlierRejectionOrdered, 
                             Job..R == "14047/2"
                             & Weight_Initial > weight
                             & AMS_Timetable_From_Results..Standard_Prep_Type == "ST"
                             )

      IAEA_C2_Bothstd = subset(SelectedRNumberOnlyOutlierRejectionOrdered, 
                               Job..R == "14047/2"
                               & Weight_Initial > weight
                               & AMS_Timetable_From_Results..Standard_Prep_Type == "Both"
                               )

R = 4        

for(i in 1:R) {
  RNumberList = NULL
  #make sure that names of the used subsets are listed in the 'list'
  RNumberList = list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition,
                     IAEA_C2_EAstd,
                     IAEA_C2_STstd,
                     IAEA_C2_Bothstd
                     )

  LoopVariable = RNumberList[[i]]
  #now I do different calculations with LoopVariable and so on

  #convert list Variable to string for later usage in filename as unique identifier!! 
  SubNameStr = deparse(substitute(RNumberList[[i]]))

  print(SubNameStr)
  # I get "RNumberList[[i]]" as string, but want for i=1 --> [1] "IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition" and for i=2 --> [1] "IAEA_C2_EAstd" and so on
  [1] "RNumberList[[i]]"
```

I do a bit of sub setting first and then I start a `for` loop from i to R where R are is the amount of subsets i put in my `list()`. Then I call `RNumberList[[i]]`, transfer it to LoopVariable and do a few calculations which (works all fine) and then I want to convert the `used subset Variable name in my list()` to a string so that this string can be used as an unique identifier in my export filename!

Comment: class of SelectedRNumberOnlyOutlierRejectionOrdered? Matrix? dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all :

```
  RNumberList = NULL #you don't need this
  RNumberList = list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition, #this needs to be before the loop otherwise
                     IAEA_C2_EAstd,          #you just overwrite it again and again
                     IAEA_C2_STstd,          #which is inefficient
                     IAEA_C2_Bothstd
                     )
```

Now:

Change the previous to:

```
RNumberList = list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition=IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition,
                     IAEA_C2_EAstd=IAEA_C2_EAstd,
                     IAEA_C2_STstd=IAEA_C2_STstd,
                     IAEA_C2_Bothstd=IAEA_C2_Bothstd
  )
```

and:

```
SubNameStr = deparse(substitute(RNumberList[[i]]))
```

to:

```
SubNameStr = names(RNumberList)[i]
```

and that's it!

I will add a small example:

```
IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition <- data.frame(a=runif(1:100))
IAEA_C2_EAstd <- data.frame(b=runif(1:100))
IAEA_C2_STstd <- data.frame(c=runif(1:100))
IAEA_C2_Bothstd <- data.frame(d=runif(1:100))

R=4
#make sure that names of the used subsets are listed in the 'list'
RNumberList = list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition=IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition,
                   IAEA_C2_EAstd=IAEA_C2_EAstd,
                   IAEA_C2_STstd=IAEA_C2_STstd,
                   IAEA_C2_Bothstd=IAEA_C2_Bothstd
)
for(i in 1:R) {

  LoopVariable = RNumberList[[i]]
  #now I do different calculations with LoopVariable and so on

  #convert list Variable to string for later usage in filename as unique identifier!! 
  SubNameStr = names(RNumberList)[i]

  print(SubNameStr)
  # I get "RNumberList[[i]]" as string, but want for i=1 --> [1] "IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition" and for i=2 --> [1] "IAEA_C2_EAstd" and so on
}
```

output:

```
[1] "IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition"
[1] "IAEA_C2_EAstd"
[1] "IAEA_C2_STstd"
[1] "IAEA_C2_Bothstd"
```